# Magento 2.4.6 & PWA 13: setting up magento 2 and PWA both on localhost

Tags: magento2, pwa, magento2.4.6

I am working on Magento 2.4.6 setup and PWA 13. Magento 2 setup is working fine and good, now I am working on setting up PWA13 environment -

The magento 2 setup url on my localhost environment is - `https://app.m2.test/`

for setting my PWA environment , when I am running command - `yarn run build`
then getting below error -

```
yarn run v1.22.19
$ yarn venia run build
$ yarn workspace @magento/venia-concept run build
$ yarn run build:prod
$ yarn run clean && webpack --no-progress --env.mode production
$ rimraf dist
FetchError: request to https://app.m2.test/graphql failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:443
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/packages/pwa-buildpack/node_modules/node-fetch/lib/index.js:1461:11)
    at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:495:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  type: 'system',
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED'
}
FetchError: request to https://app.m2.test/graphql failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:443
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/packages/pwa-buildpack/node_modules/node-fetch/lib/index.js:1461:11)
    at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:495:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
error Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: /usr/local/bin/node
Arguments: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/yarn/lib/cli.js run build
Directory: /var/www/html/packages/venia-concept
Output:

info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/workspace for documentation about this command.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

below is my .env for PWA:

```
######## PWA Studio Environment Variables ######################################
#
#   This file contains environment variables for a Magento PWA Studio project. 
#   PWA Studio uses environment variables for all variable cross-project 
#   values, so that a developer or a build system can override any variable 
#   with standard tools.
#
#   This file belongs at the root of the PWA, and must be named `.env`. 
#   Uncomment and modify variable declarations in this file and they will take 
#   effect throughout the Buildpack tool chain.
#
#   Generated by @magento/pwa-buildpack v11.4.1 on 2023-04-13T05:14:35.816Z.
#
################################################################################

#### Connecting to a Magento store #############################################
#
#   Connect to an instance of Magento 2.3 by specifying its public domain name.
MAGENTO_BACKEND_URL=https://app.m2.test/
#
################################################################################

#### Magento Store Edition #####################################################
#
#   Specify the edition of the magento store (Adobe Commerce or Magento Open 
#   Source). Can be one of MOS or AC.
#   - Default when not set: AC
MAGENTO_BACKEND_EDITION=CE
#
################################################################################

#### Magento Store View ########################################################
#
#   Specify the Magento store view code set in Stores > Settings > All Stores > 
#   Store View name
#   - Default when not set: 
STORE_VIEW_CODE=
#
#   Includes the store code in the store URLs if value is true.
#   - Default when not set: false
USE_STORE_CODE_IN_URL=false
#
################################################################################

#### Image Optimizing Origin ###################################################
#
#   Specify the origin to use for images in the UI. Set to `backend` when 
#   Fastly or another CDN is optimizing images, and the frontend will load 
#   images directly from the Magento instance at MAGENTO_BACKEND_URL. To force 
#   usage of the onboard image optimizer, set to `onboard`. Set to `auto` to 
#   autodetect whether the backend is using FastlyIO and optimize onboard only 
#   if it needs to.
#   - Default when not set: auto
IMAGE_OPTIMIZING_ORIGIN=auto
#
################################################################################

#### Default Country ###########################################################
#
#   Specify the default country to be selected in forms containing country 
#   field such as address books and shipping information forms.
#   - Default when not set: US
DEFAULT_COUNTRY_CODE=US
#
################################################################################

#### Custom local origin #######################################################
#
#   Get or create a secure, unique hostname/port combination and a trusted SSL 
#   certificate for local development.
#   - Default when not set: true
CUSTOM_ORIGIN_ENABLED=true
#
#   Add a unique hash string to the custom origin, based on filesystem 
#   location. This naturally separates domains when running multiple project 
#   folders on one developer machine.
#   - Default when not set: true
CUSTOM_ORIGIN_ADD_UNIQUE_HASH=true
#
#   Specify the subdomain prefix of the custom origin manually, instead of 
#   using the package name.
#   - Default when not set: 
CUSTOM_ORIGIN_SUBDOMAIN=
#
#   Specify the exact domain of the custom origin manually.
#   - Default when not set: 
CUSTOM_ORIGIN_EXACT_DOMAIN=
#
################################################################################

#### Development server ########################################################
#
#   Specify the hostname the dev server should bind to. If this is set, it 
#   overrides the host chosen by custom origin settings.
#   - Default when not set: 
DEV_SERVER_HOST=app.pwa13.test

#
#   Specify the port the dev server should bind to. If this is set, it 
#   overrides the port chosen by custom origin settings.
#   - Default when not set: 0
#DEV_SERVER_PORT=0
#
#   Use a service worker in developer mode (PWADevServer), which are disabled 
#   in dev mode normally to simplify cache. Good for debugging.
#   - Default when not set: false
DEV_SERVER_SERVICE_WORKER_ENABLED=false
#
#   Set to a number greater than 0 to denote a polling interval in 
#   milliseconds. If this is greater than 0, the dev server will use filesystem 
#   polling instead of native filesystem events to watch for changes. Can 
#   increase CPU usage, but sometimes is the best option for exotic filesystems 
#   (e.g. NFS).
#   - Default when not set: 0
DEV_SERVER_WATCH_OPTIONS_USE_POLLING=0
#
################################################################################

#### Staging server ############################################################
#
#   Specify the hostname the staging server should bind to. If this is set, it 
#   overrides the host chosen by custom origin settings.
#   - Default when not set: 
#STAGING_SERVER_HOST=https://app.pwa13.test/

#
#   Specify the port the staging server should bind to. If this is set, it 
#   overrides the port chosen by custom origin settings.
#   - Default when not set: 0
#STAGING_SERVER_PORT=0
#
#   Specify the id which Buildpack will put in a comment above all generated 
#   bundle files and the index.html file
#   - Default when not set: 
STAGING_BUILD_ID=
#
################################################################################

#### Onboard image optimization service ########################################
#
#   Lifetime of images in the local cache of resized images. Format is 
#   "[length] [unit]", as in "10 minutes" or "1 day".
#   - Default when not set: 1 hour
IMAGE_SERVICE_CACHE_EXPIRES=1 hour
#
#   Log image cache debug info to the console.
#   - Default when not set: false
IMAGE_SERVICE_CACHE_DEBUG=false
#
################################################################################

#### UPWARD server settings ####################################################
#
#   UPWARD configuration file to use for the PWADevServer and the "stage:venia" 
#   sample server.
#   - Default when not set: upward.yml
UPWARD_JS_UPWARD_PATH=upward.yml
#
#   Upon launching the staging server, automatically attach to a local port and 
#   listen.
#   - Default when not set: true
UPWARD_JS_BIND_LOCAL=true
#
#   Log the bound URL to stdout once the sever is listening. Useful in testing 
#   and discovery scenarios, but may be disabled in production.
#   - Default when not set: true
UPWARD_JS_LOG_URL=true
#
################################################################################

#### Checkout and payment settings #############################################
#
#   Specify a Braintree API token to direct the Venia storefront to communicate 
#   with your Braintree instance. You can find this value in Braintree's 
#   Control Panel under Settings > API Keys > Tokenization Keys.
CHECKOUT_BRAINTREE_TOKEN=sandbox_8yrzsvtm_s2bg8fs563crhqzk
#
################################################################################

#### BuildBus and targets ######################################################
#
#   A list of resolvable NPM modules that BuildBus will scan for targets, in 
#   addition to those declared in project `dependencies` and `devDependencies`.
#   - Default when not set: 
BUILDBUS_DEPS_ADDITIONAL=
#
################################################################################

#### Custom HTTPS certificates #################################################
#
#   Absolute path to the custom HTTPS certificate key file.
#   - Default when not set: 
CUSTOM_HTTPS_KEY=
#
#   Absolute path to the custom HTTPS certificate cert file.
#   - Default when not set: 
CUSTOM_HTTPS_CERT=
#
################################################################################

#### Express compression settings ##############################################
#
#   Specify if express server compression needs to be enabled. Defaults to 
#   false if not provided.
#   - Default when not set: false
ENABLE_EXPRESS_SERVER_COMPRESSION=false
#
################################################################################
```

Comment: Till now I got to understand that the above issue is comming due to SSL certificate check on magento2 installed domain, i.e. `https://app.m2.test/` , the URL is `Not Secure`. So, I have to work on generating ssl certificate for localhost env.

Comment: Which Os you have working on Ubuntu/Linux or Windows?

Comment: It's Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: So now PWA installation is done or facing any error?

Comment: installation done.